# Git Submodules: It is possible to provide both https and ssh access to submodules?

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules

Is it possible to provide both https and ssh access to a git submodule?

Some people might prefer to use https and some might only be able to use ssh (e.g. because they are behind an ssh tunnel).

Is it possible to provide both options of fetching submodules?

Comment: In the doc there is a specific URL for each submodule, maybe creating an alias or a auxiliar script would do it. Can you do this ?

Answer (score 12):

You can use relative URL when referencing a submodule.

For example if you have an application repository:

- `git@example.org:project/app.git`
- or `http://example.org/git/project/app.git`

and a library repository:

- `git@example.org:lib/some-library.git`
- or `http://example.org/git/lib/some-library.git`,

then you can reference the library as `../lib/some-library.git` instead of the full URL.